# Condition on a point on axis of the parabola so that $3$ distinct normals can be drawn from it to the parabola.

Tags: conic-sections

The question is this:

> For the parabola: $$ (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = \left(\dfrac{x+y} {\sqrt2}\right)^2 $$
>   what is the condition on the point $(h,h)$ (which lies on the axis of
>   the parabola) that $3$ distinct normals can be drawn *from* it *to* the parabola?

Now, I have this doubt: from any point *(inside the axis)* on the axis we can draw three normals to the parabola (no concrete proof, just visualisation), right? So isn't this question wrong?

Comment: What is your definition of "normal"? As far as I can see, it is possible to draw *at most* one normal on any given point on a plane curve, **unless** you're trying to embed the curve in a higher dimensional space...

Comment: I am not talking about normal *on/at* a point. My question is about the number of normals that can be *draw from that point*.

Comment: For instance, you cannot draw more than one normal from the those points of the axis which don't lie "inside" the parabola.

Comment: That's what I meant by from 'any point on the axis'. I'll edit the question. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @ParthThakkar, that didn't help at all: what is "a normal *from* some point"? I'd say it is a straightline perpendicular (or orthogonal, or **normal** ) to the curve at that point, meaning: to that curve's tangent line at that point, so again: what is *your* definition of "normal from a point"? And normal...to what?

Comment: Normal to the parabola. I think that is quite obvious as there is no other thing in the question to which normals can be drawn.

Comment: Ok, if I now understood what you want, from *any* point on the axis of the parabola contained "inside" the parabola you can draw three normals: two to each of "the sides", one more to the vertex...except from the only point on the axis belonging to the parabola, namely: the parabola's vertex

Comment: And again you didn't address the main parts of my questions, @ParthThakkar, yet *perhaps* I understood now mainly thanks to the comment of njguliyev

Comment: That's what I was asking. I am sorry for all the confusion. I'll be extra careful while asking future questions.

Comment: However, it is true that from *any* point 'inside' the parabola and lying on the axis, we can draw 3 *lines which are normal to the curve* - am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the discussion in the comments part we have, perhaps, the solution to the edited question:

From a point on the parabola's axis it is possible to draw three different normals to the parabola iff the point is contained ("inside") the parabola *but* it is not the parabola's vertex (which could be considered *not* to be "inside" the parabola, anyway...but it's better, imo, to be thorough here and mention this).

**Added:** Thanks to one of the last comments of Henning below this answer, it is possible to see that the $\,y-$intercept of *any* normal to $\,y=x^2\,$ is $\,\frac12+a^2\;$ , from where it follows that no point on the parabola's axis *and inside the parabola* can have $\,y-$intercept $\,\le\frac12\;$ and have any hope of being one of the wanted points from which three normals to the parabola can be drawn!

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me despite the poor usage of words and answering the question :D As I said, I'll be more careful with future questions

Comment: I'm not sure about that. For a point on the axis that is between the focus and the vertex, I think the axis itself is the only normal.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why would a point between the vertex and the focus on the axis be different, @HenningMakholm ?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: The normal through a point ifinitesimally close to the vertex will intersect the axis at the focus. And the farther away the point on the parabola gets, the _higher_ the intersection of its normal with the axis. There's no way to get a non-axis normal to intersect the axis below the focus.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant here by "infinitesimally close" to a point on the plane...For example, with $\,y=x^2\;$ , the focus is at $\,\left(0\,,\,\frac14\right)\;$ . From any point $\,(0,y)\;,\;y>0\;$ we can draw three normals to three different points on the parabola, one of these being the vertex $\,(0,0)\,$...am I missing something here?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm denying that you can draw three normals that intersect $(0,y)$ when $y<1/4$. Choose any point on the parabola except for $(0,0)$, and its normal will intersect the axis _above_ $(0,1/4)$.

Comment: @DonAntonio, the infintesimally close point HenningMakholm is talking about is the point infinitesimally close to the vertex *on the parabola*. The wording confused me too, but on reading 2-3 times, I understood what he says. That doesn't mean I am fully convinced about what he says.

Comment: I'm not even sure what "intersecting the $\,x-$axis  **above**  the point $\,(0\,,\,1/4)\;$ " can possibly mean...

Comment: Oops, correction -- the critical point is not actually at the focus, but the center of the circle that osculates the parabola at the vertex. I thought this was the focus, but it's actually twice as far from the vertex as the focus is.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Who said anything about intersecting the X-axis? The axis we're speaking about is the axis of the parabola (which also happens to be the $y$-axis of the coordinate system).

Comment: Ah, too bad you realized that now, @HenningMakholm : I was *almost* done with a proof...hehe. +1

Comment: Yes @HenningMakholm, with all those x's I misread "axis" by "x-axis"

Comment: @HenningMakholm, what?!? I don't understand what you mean by 'osculates the parabola at the vertex'.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I'd like to see the proof if you've almost written it.

Comment: @Parth, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle

Comment: Ah, got it. My dictionary (yes, I didn't google but *dictionaried*) called it 'intersecting at at least 3 points' - the source of all confusion.

Comment: @ParthThakkar , a sketch :at any point $\,(a,a^2)\,$ on $\,y=x^2\;$, the tangent line's given by $\;y=2ax-a^2\;$ and the normal there is $$y=-\frac1{2a}x+\frac12+a^2$$ . We can see the normal can intersect any point $\,(0,b)\;,\;b>0\;$ since $\,a+a^3=b \,,\,b>0\,$ has always a solution...

Comment: Do you mean $y=-\frac1{2a}x+\frac12\large{+}a^2 $?

Comment: Indeed so, @ParthThakkar. I corrected the last line yet I forgot to do it on the equation itself.

Comment: I don't understand 2 parts: you say the normal can intersect at any point $(0,b)$ because $a + a^3 = b$ always has a solution. How did you get there? And how do I know that the equation has always got a solution? (I am more concerned about the 1st part)

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the equation always has a solution for a positive $b$ follows from the intermediate value theorem, right?

Comment: Leave it! Understood. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Just take the $\,y-$intersect of the normal and equal it to $\,b\,$, @ParthThakkar ...About existence: differentiate wrt $\,a\,$ : $$(a^3+a)'=3a^2+1$$ and we get an increasing *continuous* function of $\;a\;$ with minimum at $\,0\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: The $y$-intercept of $-\frac{1}{2a}x+\frac 12 + a^2$ is at $y=\frac 12 + a^2$ which is always at least $\frac 12$. So points $(0,y)$ with $y<\frac 12$ _cannot_ be hit by normals from the side.

Comment: It was meant the $\,x-$intercept, @HenningMakholm...and you are right and that's *exactly* the condition Parth was looking for!

Comment: I'm with Henning here. If a point $P$ on the axis is sufficiently close to the vertex (specifically, if the radius of curvature at the vertex is greater than the distance from $P$ to the vertex), there will only be one normal from $P$ to the parabola.

Comment: After many... **many** confusions and misunderstandings, @TonyK , I added this last part of Henning's comments to the answer above and I think we can agree... *almost* ... on that.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in a more generic manner with all variables, in which case, from any point $P(h,k)$ there exist three normals to a parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ if $h> 2a$.

Comment: This seems wrong to me. If three real normals can be drawn, then $h > 2a$, not the other way around.