# $3$ distinct normals to the given parabola

Tags: conic-sections

> If $(h,k)$ be the point on the parabola $\displaystyle (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 = \frac{(x+y+2)^2}{2}$ from where $3$
>
> Distinct normal can be drawn to the parabola, Then $\min$ positive integer value of $h$

Here $(1,1)$ be the focus of the parabola and $x+y+2=0$ be the equation of directrix,

Now how can i calculate equation of parabola in standard form, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “standard form”?

Comment: Why are yo interested in the standard form? For that we need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections.   See also:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475698/condition-on-a-point-on-axis-of-the-parabola-so-that-3-distinct-normals-can-be