# condition for three distinct normals can be drawn from $(h,k)$ to Parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, cubics

Find the condition If three distinct  normals can be drawn from $(h,k)$ to Parabola whose equation is given by

$$2((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2)=(x+y)^2$$

My Try:

Since its a non standard parabola i rotated the axis by $45$ degress to get rid of $xy$ term. That is

$$x=\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$y=\frac{Y-X}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The equation got converted to as

$$X^2=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}\left(Y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Any way to proceed from here?

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475698/265466.

Answer (score 1):

I  will consider a parabola $y = a x^2 + b x + c= f(x)$.

Take a point $(p,q)$ in the plane. Joint it with a point on the parabola $(x,f(x))$. This segment will be a normal to the parabola if and only if 
$$P_{p,q}(x)=((x,f(x))-(p,q))\cdot (1, f'(x)) = 0$$

So we are looking for $x$ satisfying  the equation above, of degree $3$ in $x$. We want it to  have three real solutions. The condition is that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3)  of this cubic is $> 0$. We get a condition on $(p,q)$. The curve where this condition is $0$ is the evolute of the parabola ( see [evolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute)).

You can see a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%7B27%20x%5E2%20-%2016%20y%5E3%20%2B%2024%20y%5E2%20-%2012%20y%20%2B%202%3D%3D0,%20y-x%5E2%3D%3D0%7D,%20%7Bx,-3,3%7D,%7By,-1,5%7D%5D) of the parabola $y=x^2$ and its evolute 
$$27 x^2 - 16 y^3 + 24 y^2 - 12 y + 2=0$$ or, equivalently
$$\frac{x^2}{2}-\left(\frac{2y-1}{3}\right)^3=0$$

From points above the evolute one can draw three normals to the parabola.